# python (numpy, float, or decimal) - set min amd max decimal places in string representation

Tags: python, string, numpy, floating-point

In Python (either in regular float, numpy, or decimal), is there a way to set both a min and max decimal places when getting the string representation?

Say I want min decimal places to be 2, and max to be 6. What I want is that following

1  -> 1.00   (min to 2 decimal places)

1.00 -> 1.00

1.001 -> 1.001   (keep precision)

1.000100 ->  1.0001  (keep precision, yet drop trailing 0s)

1.000124999999 -> 1.00125  (max 6 decimal places)

My first thought is to do 
`('%.6f' % f).rstrip('0')`
This sets max precision to 6, and drops unnecessary 0s. But it doesn't do the min decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
def set_min_max(s, min, max):
    n1 = (str('%.' + str(max) + 'f') % float(s)).rstrip('0')
    if len(n1.rsplit(".")[-1]) < min:
        n1 = str('%.'+ str(min) + 'f') % float(s)
    return n1
```

---

```
min = 2
max = 6
s = '1'
print (set_min_max(s, min, max))
s = '1.00'
print (set_min_max(s, min, max))
s = '1.001'
print (set_min_max(s, min, max))
s = '1.000100'
print (set_min_max(s, min, max))
s = '1.000124999999'
print (set_min_max(s, min, max))
```

---

```
> 1.00
> 1.00
> 1.001
> 1.0001
> 1.000125
```